# How to auto set div height to fit contents?

Tags: css, height

In my script all content is loaded from a database. It's basicly one page, that retreives its info from the database, depending on which url is clicked. The content is placed into a div. So the height of the div should auto increase, in order to fit the content. With the code I have right now it doesn't. It shows all the content, but the div stays in one size. How do I solve this?

```
<div class="grid-item grid-item--width100 container">
        <div class="img"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-3x"></i></div>
        <div class="innerContainer">
            <font class="txt_registerB">Updates</font><font class="txt_registerN"></font>
            <br><br>
            //Content here
            <br>
        </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.innerContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.img {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.grid-item {
    min-width:160px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.grid-item--width100 { 
    width: calc(100% - 40px); 
}
```

Comment: FYI, the `<font>` element is obsolete and should no longer be used.

Comment: ..but try removing the `position:absolute` from the `innerContainer`. I'm not sure where you are going with that.

Comment: I know it is empty, deleted the code to make it more clear

Comment: Removing the position:absolute only makes the content lower in the div, this doesn't affect the height of the container div

Comment: A positioned element **does not add to the height of the parent**...it's taken out of the flow.